# How to get this CSS element using JavaScript (.questions label:before)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a CSS file, I have the following code.

```
.questions label:before {
content: attr(letter);
display: inline-block;
color: gray;
}
```

Using JavaScript only (jQuery not preferred), I want to make some changes to this CSS element like make the color white instead of gray.

If we were dealing only with a class name like .questions, we could do something like `document.getElementsByClassName("questions").style.color = "white";`
But I want to select the entire `.questions label:before` using JavaScript.

Comment: `document.innerHTML += "<style> .questions label:before { color: white !important; } </style>";`

Comment: you can use `document.querySelector('.questions label:before').style.color = // whatever`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: @magreenberg [Selectors API Level 1 - Grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#grammar): _"Authors are advised that while the use of pseudo-elements in selectors is permitted, they **will not match any elements in the document**, and thus would not result in any elements being returned."_

Comment: @magreenberg are you sure, did you try ? :) .. and you got upvoted too ..

Comment: Both magreenberg and Jonas W. solutions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the CSS you can simply override it with another as you cannot manipulate pseudo element using JS/jQuery because they are not a part of the DOM as you can read here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/8620333

```js
document.querySelector('.questions label').classList.add('newclass');
```

```css
.questions label:before {
  content: attr(letter);
  display: inline-block;
  color: gray;
}

label.newclass:before {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  <label letter="content ">text text</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) It seems to be the simplest solution. Also, thanks to all others who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

Use computed property to get `:before` value,

```js
var color = window.getComputedStyle(
 document.querySelector('.questions label'), ':before'
).getPropertyValue('color');
console.log(color);

function changeColor(){
    var elem = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
    var colors = ['green','blue','red'];
    elem.innerHTML = ".questions label:before {color: "+getRandom(colors)+";}";
}

function getRandom(colors){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  return colors[random];
}
```

```css
.questions label:before {
content: attr(letter);
display: inline-block;
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class='questions'>
Best
<label letter='one'> Test</label>
West
</div>

<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="changeColor()">
```

[I found this source here](https://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element)

Comment: but user ask how to change it

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that here's one

```js
var yourcss = '.questions label:before{ background-color: green }';
var yourstyle = document.createElement('style');

if (yourstyle.styleSheet) {
    yourstyle.styleSheet.cssText = yourcss;
} else {
    yourstyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(yourcss));
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(yourstyle);
```

```css
.questions label:before {
content: attr(letter);
display: inline-block;
color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  <label letter="green ">Hello World!</label>
</div>
```